# Custom UIControl not visible after launching iOS app, but visible in IB

Tags: ios, uiview, view, controls, uicontrol

i have a custom UIControl subclass (the control is from a RangeSlider tutorial). I have added a UIView and set the custom class to my RangeSlider class. The class appears in the Interface Build. However, if I start my app, the control is invisible. If I change the background color of the view, I can see it when the app is running, but the custom CALayers are not visible.

Why is that?

You can find the code here: http://pastebin.com/jrcTyybG

Comment: have you found the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the layers not in init but in viewdidload?

Comment: No because I need to declare the layers outside of the control that uses it. I do not want to do that, that sounds like bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement init(coder:) initializer.
Wrap code in init(frame:) in same method, and call him in both initializers